# How many multiples of $5$, greater than $60,000,$ can be made from the digits: $0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$

Tags: combinatorics

How many multiples of $5$ are greater than $60,000,$ and can be made from the digits: 
    $$0, 1, 2, 3, 4,  5,  6$$

if **all** digits have to be used and each can only be used once with no repeats.

Am I looking at this in the wrong way too simplistically or is it simply $2 \times 6!$

Many thanks

KM

Comment: It is not $2 \cdot 6!$ since the leading digit cannot be $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints:**

How do you know a number is divisible by $5$?

The notation of an integer can't begin with $0$.

*Some  details:*

A multiple of $5$ ends in a $0$ or a $5$. So two cases:

- If it ends in a $0$, you have to consider the $6!$ permutations of the digits $1··\,6$.
- If it ends in a $5$, you have the constraint that the leading digit cannot be $0$. You first choose the leading digit among $\{1,2,3,4,6\}$, then you have to consider the $5!$ permutations of the remaining digits, in all $5\cdot 5!\;$ numbers.

All this makes a total of
$$6!+5\cdot 5!=11\cdot 5!=1320\enspace\text{numbers}.$$
They all are greater than $60\,000$ since they are $7$-digits numbers.

Comment: Are you saying then that it should be 2 x 5!

Comment: Not quite. There's a constraint.

Comment: Hello Bernard!  I don't know what a constraint is! ....are  you able to solve this problem for me and possibly give a worked solution? Many thanks if you can help in advance. I have been asked to proof read some questions for a GCSE maths e-learning resource I am helping to develop, but this q. is beyond my level of expertise I am afraid to be honest. ........................Many thanks, Kevin

Comment: @Kevin: I've posted details. Is is clearer?

Comment: Brilliant!Thanks Bernard

Answer (score 0):

First digit can't be 0. So we have two cases.

Case 1 -

Number start with 5. Then it should be end with 0.

So we have,

$1 \times 5 \times 4 \times 3 \times 2 \times 1 \times 1$

Case 2 -

Number start with any digit except 5 or 0. Then it should be end with either 5 or 0.

So we have,

$5 \times 5 \times 4 \times 3 \times 2 \times 1 \times 2$

Comment: @robjohn we have seven digit number and 7 digit number is greater than 60000.

Comment: Sorry. I miscounted the digits available.